# Angular 2 :Sort a FireBase list observable which emits/Refer list of FBObject Observables.Sort criterion :Comparing elements of Object Observables

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I have a Firebase list Observable(**FLO**) that emits a list of Firebase Object observables(**FOO**).

1. I want to sort the set of FLO according to the elements emitted by the FOO(say 'age')
2. I wish to use the async pipe?. I want to avoid subscribing and keeping a local copy of data and thus just using async pipe.

Template:

```
<ion-row class="item-row" *ngFor="let item of itemslist|async">
    <ion-col>{{(item|async)?.someElement}}</ion-col>
```

Not a Real Code:This is what i am expecting to achive

```
this.test$ = Observable.of(['FBObjObserOne', 'FBObjObserTwo', 
'FBObjThree'])
.map((data) => {
    data.sort((a, b) => {
    //a and b are of the type firebase Object observable
        return (Some element of Obs a)<(Some element of Obs b) ? -1 : 1;
     });
    return data;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I sort data comes from fire base using this :

```
  arr.sort((a: any , b: any ) => {

    return (a.value-b.value) ;
  });
```

Where arr is the array form of data that return from fire-base. ( i.e I take the json from fire-base them make the data as array 'arr'  then sort it using this function.

Comment: Was it helpful ?

Comment: Okay when the observable return data you can sort it using this function

Comment: no it is not 
As per code i cant take a.value because a is an observable.
I have tried some thing like
`arr.sort((a:any,b:any)=>{

 a.subscribe(aData=>{
  b.subscribe(bData=>{
   this.diffrence=aData.someNumValue-bdata.someNumValue;
  }).take(1)
 }).take(1)
return(this.difference)

})`

This wont work either i think the the return is happening before the
subscribtions